# How to use cursor map / forEach with async inner function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to perform an async operation for each document in a find result. Is there a way to use cursor.map or cursor.forEach?

I've tried these two approaches but I haven't had any luck.

```
# Using map
const x = await db.collection('collectionName').find({});
x.map(async doc => return await operation(doc));
// or
await x.map(async doc => return await operation(doc));

# Using forEach
const x = await db.collection('collectionName').find({});
x.forEach(async doc => await operation(doc));
// or
await x.forEach(async doc => return await operation(doc));
```

I know I can use a while to make it work, like:

```
const x = await db.collection('collectionName').find({});

while (await x.hasNext()) {
    const doc = await x.next();
    await operation(doc);
}
```

My question is if it's possible to use map/forEach at all.

Comment: I don't think you need these `async/await`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map`, but you'll need to map each asynchonous call to a `Promise`. Then, you can call `Promise.all` on the result, which will resolve when all Promises in the passed array resolve.

There's no point in an async function that immediately `return await`s something - it's a `Promise` already, and the `await` won't make your code flatter or more readable in that situation.

So, you can use:

```
const allPromises = x.map(operation);
const resultsOfOperations = await Promise.all(allPromises);
// resultsOfOperations will be an array with the resolved values
```

That's assuming that `operation` accepts one parameter. Otherwise, you'll have to explicitly pass it each `doc`, to avoid the second and third parameters being set to the iteration index and the base array.

```
const allPromises = x.map(doc => operation(doc));
const resultsOfOperations = await Promise.all(allPromises);
// resultsOfOperations will be an array with the resolved values
```

Comment: If I try your code it fails in the `Promise.all()` line. It says `undefined is not a function`. Maybe there is something wrong with my `operation` function, however I think it's fine since it's async and returns true

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that it's not an array, so `.map` and `.forEach` aren't exactly the Array methods. Can you try using `.toArray();` to convert the input to an array first, see if it works? `const x = await db.collection('collectionName').find({}).toArray();`

Comment: That works but that will load everything into memory, I want to be able to use the cursor.

Comment: Is calling `toArray()` *after* using `.map` an option? `const allPromises = x.map(operation).toArray();` Sorry, I'm not very familiar with mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use the `Cursor.prototype.map()` method with `Promise.all()`, as in:

```
const x = await db.collection('collectionName').find({});
const promisesArray = x.map(doc => operation(doc));
const results = await Promise.all(promisesArray);
```

Unfortunately I don't think you can use `Cursor.prototype.forEach(...)` with promises, since it's implementation doesn't wait for the each promise to be resolved before going to the next entry of the cursor.

This was based taking a look at the `Cursor` implementation in MongoDB Driver API for Node [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/lib_cursor.js.html)

Comment: Does not work, It says undefined is not a function. Maybe there is something wrong with my operation function, however I think it's fine since it's async and returns true